# How interpolate a huge cloud of scattered 3D points?

Tags: 3d, interpolation, radial-basis-functions

I have a cloud consist of a million scattered 3d points. I want to get a uniform cloud of 3d points. I think to interpolate in blocks. However, as shown in the  [figure grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUiGo.png), there is a problem of block merging after interpolation. The problem is that the X and Y steps are not uniform since the blocks are offset relative to each other. How you can implement block interpolation? For interpolation I use numpy.interpolate.Rbf().

I [tried to interpolate with blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Va0.jpg) and merge them (butt lines are visible), but it is difficult to remove the joints since the blocks have different dimensions as a result of interpolation.

Comment: You can make local topological model spread. Points close to each other are encouraged to fit same model and then you build big equation system with it and you encourage some norm (for example TV) on how model parameters vary through the data. I saw this conference paper on it but dam' if I didn't forget who did it and where it was done.

Comment: You will probably get more help if you provide more details about exactly what problem you are trying to solve. What are "irregular 3D points"? You want to uniformly sample the convex hull of these points? Or something else? Also, if your question is specifically about programming using Python/numpy, you may want to ask at Stackoverflow or Data Science Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: I meant scattered 3D points.

Comment: I am interested in the method of solving the interpolation of such a large cloud of points in blocks and combining them into 1 model without distortion